# Get appointments from exchange 2016 With C#

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2016

I write some C# code that gets user appointments data from exchange server. Until now I worked with exchange 2010 and I used [EWS 2.2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42951).

Now I try to get the same data (user appointments - Title, location, time and etc).
As I could understand from reading at the internet - I can't use EWS because it's not supporting Exchange 2016.

How can I get the appointments data from Exchange 2016? Links and code examples are welcome.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

> > I can't use EWS because it's not supporting Exchange 2016

That is incorrect, EWS is fully supported on Exchange 2016 and the recently released Exchange 2019, it has been de-emphasized in favor of the Graph and REST API (but unless your using Hybrid this isn't much use). But it will work fine and is still in use by the Outlook and OWA clients. I would suggest you read this https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2018/07/03/upcoming-changes-to-exchange-web-services-ews-api-for-office-365/